# Remove outline from the template and expand it to 100%

Tags: html, css, templates, responsive-design

I am developing a website and i have a template that has a grey outline at the left, at the right, and at the bottom of it.

I would like to remove the grey outline from the template and expand the template surrounded by the gray outline to the 100% of width and height.

Please see the image above:

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SodVd.jpg)

Here is the link with the template:

http://testgraphic.altervista.org/indextoedit.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in many ways.

Because you use Bootstrap the proper way is to change your div with class `container` (who have a fixed width) with a div with class `container-fuid`

You can also keep what you have and for example (not the proper way) use :

```
.page-wrapper.container {
    width: 100% !important;
    min-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

The 100vh height is for you div take your screen height.

Comment: There also many way to do this, for example if you want exactly that you screen show you can set the width of your form to 100vw (100% of your screen) and play with margin or position to adjust the element